# Converting Cartesian coordinates to different scale using Java

Tags: java, math, coordinates, equation, cartesian-coordinates

Is there any formula that I can use to convert cartesian coordinates to different scales? In my case, x and y axes of the cartesian plane is a scale from -1 to 1. But I want to convert it to a scale of -2 to 2.

Also, the new coordinate system I using differs from the common Cartesian coordinate systems in that the orientation of the y-axis is upside down as shown in the below image.
[image]

Comment: Yes indeed, using a transformation matrix. Linear algebra is what you are looking for.

Comment: One little tip, if you need your new coordinate system just in your java application, don't convert the old coordinate system but instead use it in a clever way while printing.